# Getting error when trying to add event to google calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, google-calendar-api

When a user tries to add an event to their google calendar this error occurs: `We're sorry. There was a problem loading your calendar. Please try again in a few minutes.` I'm not sure if it's something that I'm doing in this method?

### Google URL

```
  def google_url
    "https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE\
    &text=#{CGI.escape @event.name}\
    &dates=#{@event.starts_at.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')}/\
    #{@event.ends_at.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')}\
    &ctz=#{google_time_zone}\
    &details=For+details,+link+here:+#{@event_url}\
    &location=#{CGI.escape @event.location.name}+\
    #{CGI.escape(@event.location.address)}".gsub(/\s*/, "")
  end
```

I've honestly never used this before, but it's breaking. Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) of the calendar API if it is working with you. You can use the Try It part here to create a calendar event in your calendar.

You can also follow the [Ruby code example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) here on how to create an event.

```
event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new{
  summary: 'Google I/O 2015',
  location: '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  description: 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  start: {
    date_time: '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  end: {
    date_time: '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    time_zone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  recurrence: [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  attendees: [
    {email: 'lpage@example.com'},
    {email: 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  reminders: {
    use_default: false,
    overrides: [
      {method' => 'email', 'minutes: 24 * 60},
      {method' => 'popup', 'minutes: 10},
    ],
  },
}

result = client.insert_event('primary', event)
puts "Event created: #{result.html_link}"
```